# Is this 'pmod' connector standard?

Tags: connector, identification

Here's an image of my Digilent Coolrunner II development kit:

[image]

Those connectors on the backside are 6x2, female, and seem to be on .1" pitch.  Are these standard, and where could I buy the male counterparts?  Much obliged.  Just a few words to search on is all I need. '6x2 electronic connector' didn't cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like the standard of standard connectors the 100 mil header, they may be older than engineering itself ;)   Most connector manufacturers make them in various, lengths, platings, and angle positions.   You could order a 6x2 Samtec version from digikey for $1.63 http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TD-103-T-A/SAM1114-03-ND/1105555

It says no stock, value add, but that just means they cut them to your length to order.  Pick USPS shipping if you want the best shipping deal.

Samtec is also great about sending out samples for free so if you only need a few you can request samples from their website.  Here's a link to their page for 100 mil connectors. 
http://www.samtec.com/standardboardtoboard/100_pitch_square.aspx

Molex also makes them under the CGrid or CGrid III name:  http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=cgrid_iii&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction

Those are what I usually use, although I do really like Samtec as well.   Keep in mind when ordering they come in different types of platting (and different plating thicknesses).  So if this is proto or a hobby project you'll want to get either the thinest gold or no gold to keep the price down.  This is an extremely common part so they should be easy to find.

One last tip is they're easy to cut to the size you want so I usually just buy a bag of really long ones, say 32 x 2 and then cut them to size as needed.  They're pretty useful in the lab for making test points or connectors on the fly.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure about the gender? For these application **IDC connectors** are often used, with the male boxed connector on the board, and a female connector to a flat cable:

[image]

"IDC" seems to stand for "Insulation Displacement Connector" (which is rather cryptic AFAIC).

**edit**
If the board has indeed the female connectors then they're for what's called **male headers**

[image]  [image]

At the left there's the "straight" version, right the "right-angle" version. These are for PCB mount as well, and with the straight connector your satellite board will be vertical, while with the right angle connector it will be in the development board's plane. The disadvantages should be clear: the way the connectors are placed close to each other on the development board doesn't offer the freedom the flat cables would give you. Unfortunately I haven't seen these headers for flat-cable mount. *I* would make a small adapter PCB for the header to connect to a flat-cable assembly, like a Micro-Match

[image]

which is a one-part connector for directly connecting a flat-cable to a PCB.

Comment: Yes, the dev board has the female side.

Answer (score 5):

Even though they call them "Pmod connectors", the keywords you are looking for are: `0.1" right-angle 2x6 (or 6x2) male header`.

They sell [overpriced adapters](https://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,515&Prod=PMOD-TPH2) too:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to connect self developed module by cable. It was really hard to find a 12 pin **male** header for ribbon cables.

So after searching for a while I found out that it is called "2.54mm 2x6 Pin 12 Pin Male Header IDC Ribbon Cable Transition Connector" on eBay. Those offer the gender you would like to have. Additionally 12 pins seems to be really unusual. As far as I understood that, they are normally to be soldered on the PCB. I ordered some from eBay and let you know if it worked out.